# Specifying a different DNS for certain domains

Tags: windows, networking, dns

I am located outside the US and require a DNS service to use Netflix and Hulu. However I would like to use a OpenDNS for every other resolution because it is considerably faster (ie. 30ms vs 280ms). I am using Windows 8.1.

To make clear what I'm trying to achieve, here's a solution I came across for OSX to do with creating a text file in etc/resolver (http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2004062902195410)

Answer (score 0):

According to this Server Fault [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/280158/dns-preferences-for-windows-7-client-sitting-across-two-networks) it's not possible to implement this on the Windows client-side (the question is for Windows 7 but I'm not aware of any changes in the TCP/IP stack in Windows 8/8.1 that would nullify this answer).

Comment: im not sure what to do now? i guess there really is no way. But should i close this ticket?

Comment: No, leave this question and is answers for future people who have your same question. Upvote and mark as answer the answer that best addressed your question.

Answer (score 0):

if it's for what I think you're trying, use hola in Firefox. It's an add on I've used for a few months that redirects "certain" websites for me to the American versions. I'm on my mobile so I can't link the add on. I also use it on my phone and tablet with usually good results.

Hint hint...

Comment: yes I'm familiar with hola, but it only works in the browser (when it works at all) and not on the Windows 8 Netflix app, which plays higher quality. And I needed a DNS service anyway to get my chromecast working. thanks anyways.